# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I am iterating over a list of `words` (which I didn't generate)

```
print(u'\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(w, f) for f,w in words))
```

I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The non problematic words are getting printed as expected. How can I fix this print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .encode() method:

```
print(u'\n'.join('{}:{}'.format(w.encode('utf-8'), f).decode('utf-8') for f,w in words))
```

Comment: I am now getting the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: what kind of data structure is words? is it a dict or a list?

Comment: list of tuples, `[(<str:w>,<int:f>),...]`